# Search for substring in a node name in JCR using CQ querybuilder

Tags: xpath, aem, query-builder, crx

I am trying to do a search in `CRXDE` in `CQ` using the `CQ` qurybuilder tool to find all node names(in the tree structure) that contain the character `'#'` but am not successful. Being new to the `Querybuilder` tool, I am not aware of the exact conditions to be used to do the same.
Kindly help.

I tried the following query in the `/bin/querybuilder.json tool-type=nt:file&path=/content/dam/marketinghub&property=nodename&property.value=#`

I think the `property=nodename` part is wrong. What should I mention as property name when I have to search in the node names itself and not in any specific property of the node?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, but it is not the property that you need to search, it is the name of the node.
You have a [**nodename** predicate](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/NodenamePredicateEvaluator.html) that gets this job done for you.

It accepts a pattern that you would like to search for. So in your case, the query would be

```
type = nt:file
path = /content/dam/marketinghub
nodename = *#*
```

The json querybuilder url would be

```
/bin/querybuilder.json?nodename=*%23*&path=%2fcontent%2fdam%2fmarketinghub&type=nt%3afile
```

For further learning on query builder, refer [this doc](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html).